# lapply() with XPath to obtain all text after a specific tag not working

Tags: r, web-scraping, xpath, css-selectors, rvest

**Background:**

I am scraping [this website](https://aepi.biomedcentral.com/about/editorial-board) to obtain a list of all people named under a respective section of the editorial board.

In total, there are 6 sections, each one beginning with a `<b>...</b>` part. (It actually should be 5, but the code is a bit messy.)

**My goal:**

I want to get a list of all people per section (a list of 6 elements called `people`).

**My approach:**

I try to fetch all the text, or `text()`, after each respective `<b>...</b>`-tag.

However, with the following R-code and XPath, I fail to get the correct list:

```
journal_url <- "https://aepi.biomedcentral.com/about/editorial-board"

webpage <- xml2::read_html(url(journal_url))

# get a list of 6 sections
all_sections <- rvest::html_nodes(wholepage, css = '#editorialboard p')

# the following does not work properly
people <- lapply(all_sections, function(x) rvest::html_nodes(x, xpath = '//b/following-sibling::text()'))
```

**The mistaken outcome:**

Instead of giving me a list of 6 elements comprising the people per section, it gives me a list of 6 elements comprising *all* people in every element.

**The expected outcome:**

The expected output would start with:

```
people

[[1]]
[1] Shichuo Li

[[2]]
[1] Zhen Hong
[2] Hermann Stefan
[3] Dong Zhou

[[3]]
[1] Jie Mu

# etc etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double forward slash xpath selects all nodes in the whole document, even when the object is a single node. Use the current node selector `.`

```r
people <- lapply(all_sections, function(x) {
                   rvest::html_nodes(x, xpath = './b/following-sibling::text()')
                 })
```

Output:

```r
[[1]]
{xml_nodeset (1)}
[1] Shichuo Li, 

[[2]]
{xml_nodeset (3)}
[1] Zhen Hong, 
[2] Hermann Stefan, 
[3] Dong Zhou, 

[[3]]
{xml_nodeset (0)}

[[4]]
{xml_nodeset (1)}
[1] Jie Mu, 

[[5]]
{xml_nodeset (2)}
[1] Bing Liang, 
[2] Weijia Jiang, 

[[6]]
{xml_nodeset (35)}
 [1] Aye Mye Min Aye, 
 [2] Sándor Beniczky, 
 [3] Ingmar Blümcke, 
 [4] Martin J. Brodie, 
 [5] Eric Chan, 
 [6] Yanchun Deng, 
 [7] Ding Ding, 
 [8] Yuwu Jiang, 
 [9] Hennric Jokeit, 
[10] Heung Dong Kim, 
[11] Patrick Kwan, 
[12] Byung In Lee, 
[13] Weiping Liao, 
[14] Xiaoyan Liu, 
[15] Guoming Luan, 
[16] Imad M. Najm, 
[17] Terence O'Brien, 
[18] Jiong Qin, 
[19] Markus Reuber, 
[20] Ley J.W. Sander, 
...
```